# Looking for multiple mutually exclusive occurrences in a string and rewriting it based on the result

Tags: php

First of all I would like to mention that I'm a complete noob in php and since I'm playing around with wordpress based websites I started fiddling with PHP code. I have absolutely no background in php and most of my knowledge comes from reading code and using php.net reference to undestand the causal relationships and generally what is happening.

I have come up with a solution for a problem that I have, however I feel that solution is ugly and could be optimized to be more readable and more efficient. I'm asking this question primarily as mean to learn from the answers, so if you honor me with a reply it will be greatly appreciated if you throw in a few lines of argumentation as to why this optimization is viable.

The goal of the code is to take the contents of $image_path which is just a filename of an image that has either jpg, jpeg or png file extension and rewrite that filename by adding -200x100 just before the extension(foo.jpg turns into foo-200x100.jpg). Here is the code I came up with:

```
if (strpos($image_path, '.jpeg')) {
    $image_thumb = substr_replace($image_path, '-200x100.jpeg', strpos($image_path, '.jpeg'));
}
elseif (strpos($image_path, '.jpg')) {
    $image_thumb = substr_replace($image_path, '-200x100.jpg', strpos($image_path, '.jpg'));
}
elseif (strpos($image_path, '.png')) {
    $image_thumb = substr_replace($image_path, '-200x100.png', strpos($image_path, '.png'));
}
else {
    $image_thumb = 'No image';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution matches the extension in any part of the path, which is probably not what you want:

```
$image_path = '/some/path/images.jpeg/this-is-an-image.jpeg';
```

Result:

> /some/path/images-200x100.jpeg

---

You can use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to parse `$image_path` into its components and then put them back together with modifications:

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo($image_path);

if (isset($pathinfo['extension']) && in_array($pathinfo['extension'], array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'), true)) {
    $image_thumb = sprintf('%s/%s-200x100.%s', $pathinfo['dirname'], $pathinfo['filename'], $pathinfo['extension']);
} else {
    $image_thumb = 'No image';
}
```

Result for the previous example:

> /some/path/images.jpeg/this-is-an-image-200x100.jpeg

Comment: $pathinfo['extension'] and structuring the options in an array is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!